# How can I change that regex script

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This regex:

```
$text = preg_replace("/@([^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $text);
```

.. transforms all words starting with @ into links. So it turns `@joshua` into:

```
<a href="@joshua">@joshua</a>..
```

but I need it to be:

```
<a href="joshua">@joshua</a>..
```

so without the `@` in the address of the link. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/@(\S+)/', '<a href="$1">$0</a>', $text);
```

Note: `[^\s]` can be shortened to `\S`.

Note: `$0` is preferred over `\\0` for backreferences (as stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)).

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = preg_replace("/@([^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"\\1\">\\0</a>", $text);
```

If you read the [`preg_replace` documentation](http://www.php.net/preg_replace), you notice that `\\0` is the entire match, and `\\N` is the N:th match. Since you already capture the name (the `([^\s]+)` part), you just need to change one of the `\\0`:s to `\\1`.

**EDIT:** Also from the documentation, you'll see that from PHP 4.0.4, the preferred form is not `\\N`, but `$N`. So, if you have a recent (or rather, not old) PHP version, you should change it into `$0` and `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\\1` to get the part in parentheses; `\\0` is the whole match. So all you need is

```
$text = preg_replace("/@([^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"\\1\">\\0</a>", $text);
```

Comment: `\\0` references the whole match.

Comment: I don't get you guys. Isn't this what I wrote?

Comment: @Aleks: Your first version said that `\\0` will reference the capture group and an `@` has to be added inside the link.

Answer (score -1):

```
$text = preg_replace("/(@)([^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"\\2\">\\1\\2</a>", $text);
```

This is untested, but should work.

Comment: It's a bit odd to capture a single _fixed_ character (`'@'`, in this case), and the reference is through `\1`: mind as well just use `@` in the replacement string...

Comment: Oh, and `\\0\\1` would become: `"@joshua@"` (`\0` -> `@joshua` and `\1` -> `@`)

Comment: Just to keep as close as possible to the original code. It's not a good idea to dazzle a learner too much.

Comment: I don't agree that you're keeping it as close to the original code: the OP wasn't capturing the `@` by itself. Besides, your answer _was_ wrong before you revised it...

Comment: It was wrong, ... and I saw my error and changed it before you posted your correction...